# Regarding differentiability at $x =0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined by
$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2 \text{ if $x$ is rational}\\
x^4 \text{ if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$

Is $f$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

How do I begin ?

Comment: We're looking for $\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}$ and close enough to $0$ we have $|f(x)|\leq x^2$ because $|x^4|\lt |x^2|$ for $|x|\lt 1$

Comment: The squeeze theorem may be useful.

Comment: @marwalix Why this $f(x)/x$ ,

Comment: What is the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$?

Comment: @JPG Revert to the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Definition of differentiability at $0$ is the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is:

For $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon\}$. Let $u$ be such that $0 <|u| < \delta$.

If $u \in \mathbb Q$, then:

$$\left| \frac{f(u)}{u} \right| = |u| < \delta < \epsilon$$

If $u \notin \mathbb Q$, then:

$$\left| \frac{f(u)}{u} \right| = |u^3| \le |u| < \delta < \epsilon$$

Comment: why have you taken delta to be minimum of 1 and epsilon ??

Comment: @JPG: to use: $|u^3| \le |u|$.

Comment: Can you clarify more about this point ,How?

Comment: Well done! A +1

Comment: @JPG: if $\epsilon >1$, say $2$  then if you took $\delta =\epsilon$ and $u$ happened to be say $1.5$ then you'd have $\vert u\vert <\delta $ but $\vert u\vert ^{3}>\epsilon$ Bottom line: $\delta $ needs to be < $1$ AND less than $\epsilon $ so you just take the min of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Following the definition, you begin asking yourself the following:
$$
\exists\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}?
$$
If so then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and the above limit equals $f'(0)$.
Now, if $|h|<1$ then clearly $|f(h)|\leq h^2$. In particular, 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(h)|}{|h|}=0.
$$ As $f(0)=0$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=0.
$$ Thus, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.